# Can't use TextField in UITextFieldDelegate class initializer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums, delegates, textfield

I have an `enum` that I use in a class used as a `UITextFieldDelegate`

Enum:

```
enum Position {
//Enum for Position variable in MemeTextDelegate

case Top, Bottom
init () {   //set outside of enum to .Bottom if needed
    self = .Top
}
```

UITextFieldDelegate Class:

```
class MemeTextDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var position = Position()
    var userEnteredText = false //Default value

    override init () {
        switch (position) {
        case (.Top):
            textField.text = "TOP"
        default:
            textField.text = "BOTTOM"
        }
    }

    //Methods removed for this example...
}
```

In the `ViewController`, I set each TextField's delegate so it knows it's 'Top' or 'Bottom'

```
@IBOutlet weak var topTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomTextField: UITextField!

let topTextFieldDelegate = MemeTextDelegate()
let bottomTextFieldDelegate = MemeTextDelegate()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Set Delegates
    self.topTextField.delegate = self.topTextFieldDelegate
    self.bottomTextField.delegate = self.bottomTextFieldDelegate

    //Set individual fields delegate properties for TOP and BOTTOM
    self.topTextFieldDelegate.position = .Top
    self.bottomTextFieldDelegate.position = .Bottom
}
```

Each line with `textField.text` in `MemeTextDelegate` gets a compiler error that reads: "Use of unresolved identifier 'textField'", while using `textField` within methods is no problem at all.

I am sure I am missing something fundamental, so any input helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code that you have presented, the MemeTextDelegate does not own an instance of textField.  Presumably, it would only come from a delegate method.  Yet, you are referring to it in your init method.